# How to compress files on azure data lake store

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake

I'm using Azure data lake store as a storage service for my Java app, sometimes I need to compress multiples files, what I do for now is I copy all files into the server compress them locally and then send the zip to azure, even though this is work it take a lot of time, so I'm wondering is there a way to compress files directly on azure, I checked the [data-lake-store-SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-java-sdk), but there's no such functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, at the moment there is no option to do that sort of compression.

There is an open feature request [HTTP compression support for Azure Storage Services (via Accept-Encoding/Content-Encoding fields)](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/3388309-http-compression-support-for-azure-storage-service) that discusses uploading compressed files to **Azure Storage**, but there is no estimation on when this feature might be released.

The only option for you is to implement such a mechanism on your own (using an **Azure Function** for example).

Hope it helps!